# Service subscription initiate multiple time inside ngOnInit [Angular 2]

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have problem that when i go to diffent pages and return bank to first page where is this component:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.getModal();
}

getModal() {

this.subscription = this.sharedService.itemEdit$.subscribe((bank: any) => {
            console.log("TEST")
            this.subscription.unsubscribe();
        });
}
```

I get multiple subsciption even I call emit service just one time.

Anyone know what can be a problem?

Comment: The ngOnInit and ngOnDestroy are being called everytime you go away and come back to this component. That's how it should work.

What you should be doing is handle the ngOnDestroy also and unsubscribe from there.

`ngOnInit() {
  this.getModal();
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  if(this.subscription) this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to unsubscribe inside `ngOnDestroy` just before Angular destroys the directive/component.Check Angular [Lifecycle hook](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html#!#ondestroy)

```
ngOnDestroy() {
  if(this.subscription) {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Should I call `ngOnDestroy` in each component where I have events and observables?

Comment: @VladimirDjukic if the component's lifecycle is not as long as the app itself, then yes you should. Say a navigation bar that is always displayed on your page no matter where you navigate to, than subscriptions in the navbar component does not need to be unsubscribed onDestroy.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to [ranakrunal9's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41378283/1518765), that might be helpful if you have multiple subscriptions, is to setup a destroyed$-trigger and use `.takeUntil(this.destroyed$)`:

```
class SomeComponent {
    destroyed$ = new Subject();

    ngOnInit() {
        this.sharedService.itemEdit$
            .takeUntil(this.destroyed$) // this will automatically complete the stream when destroyed and therefor close the subscription
            .subscribe(...);

        this.sharedService.otherStream$
            .takeUntil(this.destroyed$)
            .subscribe(...);

        this.sharedService.streamThree$
            .takeUntil(this.destroyed$)
            .subscribe(...);
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.destroyed$.next();
    }
}
```

---

As an additional side-note: Try to **avoid manual subscriptions** in components, a component is usually there to display data, for which the [`async`-pipe](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/AsyncPipe-pipe.html) can be used, which will handle `subscribe` and `unsubscribe` automatically so you don't have to worry about all that.

If something perpetual(like a background-task) is going on, use a service.